# java inputstream not reading leading hex bytes

Tags: java, sockets

I've got a Telnet Client defined as:

```
    TelnetClient telnet = new TelnetClient();
    telnet.connect(server, port);
```

I then get the inputstream:

```
    InputStream in = telnet.getInputStream();
```

and then try to read stuff on it, in a loop:

```
    while (true) {
    int TEST = in.read();
    }
```

everything seems to go fine as I receive the "text" part of the input... but I'm missing the (very important for me!) leading bytes.
Here is a snoop of what I see going on the port:

```
    64: a88f ffff 3034 3131 3032 3030 3030 3030    ¨...041102000000
    80: 3030 322e 3031 3131 2e36 2e34 2020 3135    002.0111.6.4  15
    96: 2e39 2e33 2020 3030 3132 30                .9.3  00120
```

notice the "ffff": that's the leading part I need (everything before is garbage: part of the TCP communication).

However, when printing my "TEST" variable, I only see the "041102...etc".

I've tried using BOMInputStream too, but I can't get it either.

=> would you have any idea on how I can receive those ?

Thanks for your help !

Comment: How are you "snooping what's going on the port"?

Comment: using the Solaris snoop command:
snoop -x 0 port XXXX

Comment: Is that potentially part of the packet header then, rather than actual data? Or perhaps it's a telnet header? (Do you *need* to use TelnetClient here, rather than just a normal network connection?)

Comment: - no, I don't need to use TelnetClient actually ... I might try with a Socket connection instead (but leaving for the week end now - bad timing)
- as for the part I need (ffff), that's part of the data, that's for sure (I used wireshark to confirm that, and also, I managed to get the "same" code working in Perl)
thanks already for the idea of trying with something else ... I should have thought of it, but Friday evening does not help

Answer (score 2):

The input stream provided by a `TelnetClient` instance is only going to provide the data characters.  Telenet protocol signalling stuff will have been filtered out by the `TelnetClient` code.

If you want to get hold of the signalling information, options, etcetera, you will need to use other methods in the `TelnetClient` API.  There are a variety of approaches you could possibly try.  For example, you could register an option handler, or a notification handler, or you could register a "spy stream".

Answer (score 1):

You should be just using `Socket` instead of `TelnetClient` if you really want to see all of the data.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try that on Monday morning